# Excel VBA PasteSpecial Add is Inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I have a workbook (.xls) that is generated from a proprietary piece of software which contains dates which Excel recognises only as a string (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss).

There are roughly 18000 rows and 10 columns. I can get Excel to convert these manually by copying a blank cell, selecting the relevant range and then doing PasteSpecial -Values -Add. Alternatively, I can use "Text to Columns" on each column to trigger the change to proper Excel date format.

I want to do this via a VBA subroutine (example code below).

```
    Range("E1").Select 'blank cell
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A8").Select 'top left of range
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select 'to bottom right
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
```

However, this only seems to affect c.35% of the selected cells.
Interestingly this is also the case when I try and use alternative VBA code to do the "Text to Columns" column by column.

I am stuck: do you have any idea why this is happening, and are there any alternatives?

Comment: Can you share a subset of your file somewhere like Dropbox? You want the dates to keep the same original format but as dates?

Comment: Link to .xls [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/156yOORdVvBaj-kYWifyIHusU3kQVS9na/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115867755187373933257&rtpof=true&sd=true). I want the dates to be considered as dates by Excel (i.e. numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very weird the date format in csv file. After converting Data to Text, some of the dates are a character longer than others and I could not find which character it was. Certainly is a non print character!

This procedure is based on the file you posted. The procedure loops from column D to H, correcting the datetime values and then copying them to the original column as values.

Add the other datetime columns that you might have, after testing and if this is ok to you.

```
Sub FormatCSVDates()
    Dim tmpRng As Range
    Dim tmpCol As Integer: tmpCol = Range("AA8").Column
    
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim startCol As Integer: startCol = 4   ' column D
    Dim endCol As Integer: endCol = 8       ' column H
    Dim col As Integer


    For col = startCol To endCol
        ' clear helper column
        Range("AA8").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    
        ' column range to format(source range)
        Set srcRng = Range(Cells(8, col), Cells(8, col).End(xlDown))
                
        ' temporary range
        Set tmpRng = srcRng.Offset(0, tmpCol - col)
        
        ' Insert formula in temporary range
        tmpRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(DATEVALUE(RC[-" & tmpCol - col & "]),TIMEVALUE(RC[-" & tmpCol - col & "]))"
        
        ' copy formula to values
        tmpRng.Copy
        tmpRng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
        ' copy from temporary range to source range
        tmpRng.Copy srcRng
        
        ' format sorce range
        srcRng.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"
    Next col
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' clear helper column
    Range("AA8").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help: I hadn't thought of using DATEVALUE + TIMEVALUE :)